# PHP Validate Error

Tags: php, md5, captcha

Working on a send link to a friend form.
Seeking to provide for defeat spambots by presenting form filler with a code (visitorcode) to imput into a box.

```
if (trim($_POST ["md5($visitorcode)"] == $_SESSION['image_random_value'])) 
$errors[] = "<b>Validate Code:</b> ".$form_items["visitorcode"]["error"];
```

When correct Validate code is installed I want error to clear so that the thanku.html can be presented.I am doing something wrong as it will not work. Can anybody shine a light or give direction?
Full code and problem available at www.shopdemo.webitry.net

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
md5(trim($_POST[$visitorcode]));
```

Comment: Thanks PMV, I tried this correction into the page code and yes it removed the error notification! However I do not want the error notification to remove until the required visitorcode (from the random image) is installed correctly into the input box!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to type:

```
if (trim($_POST[md5($visitorcode)]) == $_SESSION['image_random_value'])
```

or, as PMV mentions:

```
if (md5(trim($_POST[$visitorcode])) == $_SESSION['image_random_value'])
```

But either way you misplaced some parentheses and double-quotes in the original code.

EDIT:

It looks maybe like you are dealing with errors in the body of the `if` clause. That being the case, shouldn't the `if` statement use `!=` instead of `==`? I.e., if they don't match, deal with errors.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan M, I tried this correction into the page code and yes it removed the error notification! However I do not want the error notification to remove until the required visitorcode (from the random image) is installed correctly into the input box! I must have other misplaced items in the code!

Comment: Tried != and now the Form calls the thanku.html However, it does so in the following 3 scenarios: 1. Without a visitorcode installed 2.With a incorrect visitorcode installed and 3. With correct visitorcode installed! Are this getting closer to a resolve?

Comment: Update - with != installed the error warning is presented but form will not accept visitor code or pass to Thanku.html. Does this provide for any pointers as to where I should be looking?